# Linear operator cancellation

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this by looking at Green's function [motivation topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function):

suppose that $L$ is a linear operator (acting on a function, distribution (as in this case) or whathever). Take the equation:
$$L \left (u(x) \right)=\int L \left (G(x,s) \right)f(s)ds $$
Suppose moreover that $L$ does not act on the variable "$s$", so:
$$L(u(x)) =L \int G(x,s)f(s)ds$$
Now as you can read on the text, this "suggest" the equation:
$$ u(x)=\int G(x,s)f(s)ds$$

---

Could you give me clarification on this last step?
Is this always true,indipendently of what kind of linear operator $L$ is and indipendently on what it acts on?

E.g. , suppose that $L$ acts on vectors:
$$ L\mathbf{x}=L\mathbf{y} $$
to get the equation $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y} $ I should multiply both members by $L^{-1}$ and this looks me "prone" to the existence of the inverse.

Comment: If there exists an inverse that is true. However if you have a nontrivial nullspace you can not omit the operator. Take for example the (linear) differentiation operator.

Comment: Yes, E.g $ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left ( x+y \right )=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left ( x \right )$ is different from $x+y=x$. So according to this, we can omit the operator if the kernel has dim=0, right? This is what do you mean for "trivial" ?

Comment: Exactly. Another thing: If the operator is fixed you could also try to restrict it's domain to achieve a trivial nullspace. In this example: if you already know that your functions $f$ and $g$ are BOTH of form $c_1\sin(x) + c_2\cos(x)$ you can deduce that $f=g$ even though your operator has nontrivial kernel on it's "natural" domain $C^1$.

Comment: Another way to put it: $ L\mathbf{x}=L\mathbf{y} $ implies that $ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y} +\mathbf{z}$ where $\mathbf{z}\in\ker L$.